# Gape between http requests in the browser - loading media resources

Tags: performance, asynchronous, dom, browser

I get this delay (first image below) of almost 4s before the media resources start downloading, for the scond request the gap is negligible.

Even when I allow the browser to use the cache, the same behavior occurs.

I tried to load the media resources after DOMContentLoaded event but I got the same behavior.

- First Request URL : http://subdomain_1.domain.com (HTML content loaded in ~3s )

[image]

- Second Request URL : http://subdomain_2.domain.com (HTML content loaded in ~1s )

[image]

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Added a 1s timeout to avoid the gape i.e. to load media ressources after DOMContentLoaded event.